# How to add roles in IBM Tivoli Identity Manager

Tags: java, security, tivoli-identity-manager

I want to assign ITIM users, roles/groups so that I can block them from operations they are not authorized for.

This concept is same as j2ee security roles.

How to create roles/groups in ITIM? How to assign it to users in ITIM?

Comment: typing the question of your question as is in google points to a lot of documentation. what have you tried? what specifically is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try develop the workflows into iTIM and try to align it with the current workflows involved. In fact what you are asking cannot be just explained into a single answer as iTIM assignment of roles goes through a number of other processes. Still you can refer a few IBM documents available on same. Recently we had developed a similar thing and had to put a lot of time/research onto this.